# How can I pass props around my app in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Have been plagued by the following problem and am unsure of how I can proceed. Any help is very appreciated!!

Basically, I would like to pass props from my tabs component to my moviedetail component.
I am also trying to use async storage for this. But am unsure on how to implement.
The use case is that I would like to show a movielist with a button that is conditionally rendered based on whether its a favourited movie or not.

I have a stack navigator in my app.js that serves as a base to all navigation.
App.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MovieDetail" component={MovieDetail} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Tabs.js

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 25,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: '#393E41',
          borderRadius: 15,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          height: 90,
          ...styles.shadow
        }
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabIcon focused={focused} icon={HomeIcon} label={'Home'} />
          )
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="About"
        component={AboutScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabIcon focused={focused} icon={AboutIcon} label={'About'} />
          )
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favourites"
        component={FavouritesScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabIcon focused={focused} icon={FavouritesIcon} label={'Favourites'} />
          )
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

HomeScreen.js

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar hidden />
      <Text style={styles.title}>database.io</Text>
      <ScrollView>
        <MovieList
          movies={movies}
          setMovies={setMovies}
          title={'Top 20'}
          navigation={props.navigation}
        />
      </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Is there a way to do this? I have tried passing props using initialParams but it dosen't persist.

Im thinking of something like the following:
where i pass the favouriteList state from App to Tabs, and thereafter from Tabs to its individual screens.
App.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} favouriteList={favouriteList}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="MovieDetail" component={MovieDetail} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

then in Tabs.js

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 25,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: '#393E41',
          borderRadius: 15,
          borderTopColor: 'transparent',
          height: 90,
          ...styles.shadow
        }
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        favouriteList={props.favouriteList}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabIcon focused={focused} icon={HomeIcon} label={'Home'} />
          )
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="About"
        component={AboutScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabIcon focused={focused} icon={AboutIcon} label={'About'} />
          )
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favourites"
        component={FavouritesScreen}
        favouriteList={props.favouriteList}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabIcon focused={focused} icon={FavouritesIcon} label={'Favourites'} />
          )
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a global state for your app. It will be a better approach to props drilling. It can be achieved natively using React's `context` API or you can you any state management libraries (redux, mobx etc.)

- [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

The overall idea is to have a single source of data that can be consumed from anywhere in your app's component  tree.

[image]

But, if you want to pass the data using props to each page, you can do this like below:

```
navigation.navigate("Screen", payload); // payload is the data you want to pass to Screen
```

to consume the data, you can do like below:

```
const payload = route.params;
```

A demo of this approach is here: [data passing](https://github.com/chankruze/rn-todo-app/blob/868026fcacd78a2e9c67582029c85a3dd4e33d8d/screens/Home.tsx#L30), [data consuming](https://github.com/chankruze/rn-todo-app/blob/868026fcacd78a2e9c67582029c85a3dd4e33d8d/screens/Task.tsx#L14)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Would you happen to know how i can pass them from routes to routes or would context api be the way to go? the navigation.navigate for my bottom tab dont seem to work.

Comment: Context would be better. Passing a huge list from routes to routes is not optimal. If my answer helped, please mark as selected. ;)